# How to get the group that a user belongs to in SCO

Tags: users, group, sco

I can see how to add a user, but is there a way to get information on a user, such as the group that it belongs to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes :

`id userlogin`

This will show you uid(and name) of the userlogin, followed by his primary group gid (and name) then all the groups *userlogin* belongs to Gid(s) (and name(s))

You can also specify some options like :

```
id -g userlogin     # gives only the gid
id -ng userlogin    # gives group name instead of gid
id -G userlogin     # gives list of group(s) id(s)
id -nG userlogin    # gives list of group(s) name(s)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
groupls         Lists what groups you are in.
groupls (username)
groupls -a      Lists all groups
```

(taken from: [OSR600 Docs](http://osr600doc.sco.com/en/manADM/groupls.ADM.html))

System administration tools are in `/etc` on SCO, so if you don't have this directory in your PATH, you'll need to specify the full PATH: `/etc/groupls`

Comment: unfortunately groupls is not found on my distro: SCO OpenServer(TM) Release 6.0.0

Comment: @Kevdog777, which distribution do you use?  
Maybe it's a kind of alias or function defined in your shell.  
e.g : `function groupls () { id -G $1; }`  
to check weather you got a such thing in your shell use the command `declare -f groupls`

Comment: The source of `groupls` is confirmed. That's a legit command so this A is completely valid and should be UV'ed.

Comment: @ldgorman Really? Note that it's in `/etc` (SCO is very old-fashioned), which may not be in your PATH.

Comment: @Gilles turns out it was missing from PATH. this is a perfectly valid answer.